How to read the sutras in the Astadhyayi of Panini?
I have this Amazon copy of Astadhyayi of Panini, which shows pages like these:

What does, for example, this mean?
1.1.7 ha̱Laḥ=ánantarāḥ saṁyogáḥ

I assume the sutras are what are numbered with the 3 numbers like 1.1.7. It appears the capital letters are some sort of special code?

And after talking with a person in India, shared https://www.sanskrit-trikashaivism.com/en/scriptures-sanskrit-grammar-ashtadhyayi-chapter-1/960 which has the devanagari and alternative romanization, which is nice (but isn't 100% translated). So it says:
१.१.७ हलोऽनन्तराः संयोगः।
1.1.7 Halo'nantarāḥ saṁyogaḥ|
Continuous (anantarāḥ) consonants (halaḥ) --i.e. consonants without any vowel in between-- (form) a conjunct (saṁyogaḥ).

So how do you go about reading this book? If not the book specific syntax, the website romanization just linked? How do you learn how to interpret each line?

Why the = sign?
How do you interpret what is a command vs. what is something else, etc.?

Basically, what do I need to read or know to interpret these numbered statements?
I guess the original Devanagari Astadhyayi is here (for reference), but that isn't much use to me yet.
